# Retrieve simple product price for configurable product on sales_order_place_before event

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, simple-product

I am using magento 1.9.2

I have configurable product product 'whey'

I want to get price for simple product

[image]

I used getPrice(); in `sales_order_place_before` event

But it is giving me 1196.25 (wrong price)

I want 1595, How can I get it

Please help.

I make this changes in database

```
ALTER TABLE sales_flat_order_item ADD COLUMN product_mrp DECIMAL(12,4) NULL;
ALTER TABLE sales_flat_invoice_item ADD COLUMN product_mrp DECIMAL(12,4) NULL;
ALTER TABLE sales_flat_shipment_item ADD COLUMN product_mrp DECIMAL(12,4) NULL;
```

Then in `Mage_Sales_Model_Observer`

```
public function saveProductMrpInOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $price = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId())->getPrice();
            $item->setProductMrp($price);
            Mage::log("Order placed successfully with getOrder event '$price'");
        }
      return $this;
    }

    public function saveProductMrpInInvoice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
        foreach($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $price = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getPrice();
            $item->setProductMrp($price);
            Mage::log("Order placed successfully with with getInvoice event '$price'");
        }
    }
      return $this;
    }

    public function saveProductMrpInShipment(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        foreach($shipment->getAllItems() as $item) {               
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $price = $product->getPrice();
            $item->product_mrp = $price;
            Mage::log("Order placed successfully with with getShipment event '$price'");
        }
    }
```

Then in invoice I am using `getProductMrp()` to get price

Answer (score 0):

If you use **getPrice() use then it  will given you Cart item price**.

In order to get Simple product price use `getProduct()->gePrice()` or `getProduct()->geFinalPrice()` .Those are `given product price which shown at product page,category pages` because of `getProduct()` object of model class `(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)`
\
**edit:**

`saveProductMrpInOrder` function

**change**

```
$price = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId())->getPrice();
            $item->setProductMrp($price);
```

**to**

```
$price = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getPrice();
/* load Sales Order item model */
$TemOrderItem=Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load$item->getId())   ;       
$TemOrderItem->setProductMrp($price);
$TemOrderItem->save();
```

**Explain u later**

Comment: Its's not working @AmitBera

Comment: Can you plz share your code?

Comment: I added code in question @AmitBera Please help

Comment: `saveProductMrpInOrder` is working but `saveProductMrpInInvoice` is not working , showing wrong price for `getProductMrp` @AmitBera

Comment: please help @AmitBera

Comment: Is it possible to get price @AmitBera

Comment: it is possaible but i am little lit of busy now

Comment: ok, tell me when you get time, I am working on it from past 5 days @AmitBera